# How do I stop my canon selphy cp1300 from printing out dull looking pictures?

Tags: canon

The original pictures are very bright but whenever I print them out, they come out looking duller than the original.

I only brought this printer last week and I was so excited to get it I do not want to return it. I have followed all the steps correctly - i put in the ink cartridge correctly and inserted the paper folder correctly too.

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: OK, i have to say it.   "*How do I stop my canon selphy cp1300 from printing out dull looking pictures?*" Stop taking dull looking pictures. ;)   Best guess: The camera is showing you a preview of what the photo "could look like" not what it actually does looks like.   **More info is needed**.  What kind of files are you shooting to, JPG's ? You are printing directly to the printer  and not doing any post production with software on a computer?  Please explain what you are doing and how you are getting the files from the camera to the printer.

Comment: It's either a profiling mismatch or a screen calibration issue… but we're never going to really know which. As it stands, I'd recommend asking Canon for initial guidance.

Comment: I am using the canon print app to print my pictures directly from my photo album

Comment: Are you taking images and printing directly from your phone? Or are you using software on a computer to print? Are you using Canon paper specifically made for the SELPHY dye-sub process (KC-18IF, KC-18IL, KC-36IP, KP-36IP, KP-108IN, RP-54, and RP-108)?

Comment: yes i am taking the pictures on my phone and printing them directly from my phone. I use the Canon app to print the pictures and I used the Canon RP0108IP papers and ink.

Comment: @inkista You can only print with the original paper. And you always get paper and transfer sheets in a set.

Comment: Yeah, experimentation shows that there are about three ways to correct this problem.

Comment: a) @KaiMattern way with colour management; Do a colorimeter read on the printout and create a filter for Photoshop to adjust the image based on the output. The white balance is pretty ok, the saturation not so much. Obviously the photos will then look wrong on your Spyder-calibrated screen, for any other people and will print wrong on another make of printer which manufacturer actually supports colour management on eg Pixma MG7700. 
b) Copy photos to memory card and print them directly from printer with "vivid" setting. 
c) Print from Mac, based on internets, not tried myself.

Comment: Fourth option is to print on a printer which you get proper icc profile for but you will need to have the photos laminated or otherwise preserved as inkjet photos do not tolerate exposure to air well, which is exactly why we wanted a sublimation printer in the first place for photos handed out to relatives etc. You can use Adobe RGB here for better colour space if your printer does >sRGB. 
Fifth option, forget about the whole thing and just have the photos printed online, although these vary on quality. If they allow you to define the colour profile, that's a good sign.

Answer (score 5):

All the other answers are too general. Specifically for this printer (I have the CP1200, pretty much the same):

- Print from an SD card plugged into the printer (the below settings don't seem to change on wifi, at least for me)
- Go into the menu options, and:

  - Turn Image Optimize to Off
  - Brightness set to +1
  - My Colors set to Vivid

Then they come out significantly better than default.

Comment: Canon drivers used to have same settings (brightness, saturation) but they have been removed in CP1200 Windows 10 driver at least.

Comment: I think I'll go with this route myself, I'm tired of trying to make this work with the plug'n'play windows driver Canon gives us with zero options. It appears that Mac driver version in fact works just fine, probably Canon creative people use Macs and would throw a fit otherwise. The best you can do directly is to use a "Selphy" photoshop filter which will apply the required correction and print that. That's a horrible kludge tho and your photos will then look and print wrong on anything else. You're probably much better off keeping the photos as they are and copying them on sRGB to SDCARD.

Comment: I've tried couple of icc profiles but they're not perfect as they are and you have no means to tweak the output even a little on the drivers, so ..

Comment: I had to get a new SD Card adapter as I lost the previous one but I can now confirm this route, copying exact same images to SD Card and printing them from printer produces expected results. I'm not sure you want to touch brightness (adjust to taste obviously) but "vivid" does corrects the dull colours this printer produces (on Windows). Perhaps Mac drivers do not have this issue but I have no Mac to try with.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably a mix between a lack of understanding and a mismatch of monitor calibration.

I have the very same printer and use it as a low end printer to fabricate water resistant prints.

**Understanding the difference between monitor and print**

While a monitor image is emitting light by itself, the printed image can only be a light as the reflected light of the paper medium. This means that most images are far less brighter than on the screen. If you want to achieve a good print, you will have to optimize the photo for printing.

Additionally some colors cannot easily be reproduced by the 4 standard printing colors (cyan magenta yellow and black). Expensive specialized photo printers use more than these 4 colors to help the printing process for better color rendition.

**Monitor settings**

Most consumer monitors are set way too bright and the color contrast is set quite harsh. If you optimize an image on a monitor with these settings, the image will look more colorful and brighter than it really is. If you print it, you will see the mismatch very clearly.

You could use a professional colorimeter to calibrate your monitor, but there is a cheaper way, which might help in your case. Go into the settings of the printer and switch color optimization off. Then print a colorful image of you choice. Make sure it is a sRGB jpg. Now take the print, and try to set the brightness of the monitor so that ii is a bit similiar to the image. If the colors are very off, see if you can achieve a better match with the contrast settings.

Now see what you can achieve by editing the image and saving it as a sRBG jpg. If you edit it to be colorful and print it now, it should be closer to what you are getting.

However, the printer is a low end consumer device. The quality is about the same as the prints you get from a drug store or instant printing service.

**Other color spaces**

You should absolutely make sure that the images are in the SRGB color space (that is the base space for images on the web). Other stuff would be Adobe RGB, ProPhoto RGB and CMYK. These will be converted, with a loss of color rendition. I do not think, that this is the problem here, though.

Comment: Mod note: I have [moved this conversation to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130592/discussion-on-answer-by-kai-mattern-how-do-i-stop-my-canon-selphy-cp1300-from-pr). Reminder, please keep it civil and [be nice](//photo.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 0):

Your printer does not have its own adjustments.   It is not possible to balance the image on the camera with the print unless you use an external software to do the printing.  For example, you must load the image into Photoshop and set the interface to let Photoshop manage colors.  You can then make your the adjustments to the image and print with more control.

Answer (score 0):

Prints will come out looking too dark because you have edited your photo on a screen that is too bright. The simple solution is after taking your photo, edit it with your phones display or whatever display you use to at least 50% brightness. This will make your print look much brighter.